# Rspec and watir-webdriver; assert element not present

Tags: rspec, watir-webdriver, assertions

I'm using Rspec and watir-webdriver and am struggling to write a passing test so that when an item is deleted on screen, that it *is not* present--and therefore passes Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
# this method gets the specific item I want to interact with
def get_item(title)
    foo = @browser.div(:text, title).parent.parent
    return foo
end

# This method looks at an element grid that contains all the items
def item_grid_contents
    grid = @browser.div(:class, 'items-grid')
    return grid
end
```

When I delete the item, these are a few of the ways I've tried to write my assertion:

```
expect(get_item(title)).not_to be_present # => fails, unable to locate element
expect(item_grid_contents).not_to include(get_item(title)) # => fails, same error
```

In this case, I am looking to ensure that the element *cannot* be located, and should pass. 
Is there another way to write this so it is considered a pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check if `div(:text, title)` is present?  after all if the outer container (parent) is gone, then so would be the contents (child).

```
expect(@browser.div(text: title)).not_to be_present
```

or  (not sure I have my expect syntax right here..)

```
expect(@browser.div(text: title).present?.to be_false
```

small note re ruby..  you can make those methods a little cleaner by not bothering with an intermediate variable.  You can in fact even eliminate 'return' as it's implied (but some of us like it for readability) Also most folks writing Ruby code use two space indents. So for your above methods, you could just use

```
def get_item(title)
  return @browser.div(:text, title).parent.parent
end
```

or even

```
def item_grid_contents
  @browser.div(:class, 'items-grid')
end
```

Comment: Thanks--this was the solution that worked the easiest for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `#parent` method uses javascript to find the Selenium element from which it creates the Watir element. For most elements, Watir creates an xpath locator, but lazy loads it so that it doesn't have to be present until it is interacted with. With this javascript call, it is evaluated immediately, so it fails immediately without being able to respond to `#exists?` or `#present?` methods.

This is an excellent example for why I don't like our current implementation of parent. I've been sitting on code to change this for a while since I haven't had a compelling reason to push for it. This is a compelling reason.

For now, I think this will work for you:

```
@browser.div(:text, title).element(xpath: './ancestor::*[2]')
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without using an xpath?

Comment: Not until/unless we on the Watir team change the implementation of the parent method. My desire is to literally implement it with that xpath. The only real downside with xpath is its readability, and at least this one is pretty obvious what it is doing.